# Percentiles (values corresponding to the percentiles)

Tags: r

I have columns of <customers> and <sales>. I want to calculate the <sales> values, corresponding to the relevant percentiles of <customers>. (e.g. sales volume corresponding to the upper 1% of customers, upper 10% of customers etc....

Hayk

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and consider to add some sample data so we can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the `quantile()` function. If you have a vector of values called `a` then you can compute the percentiles you want with:
`quantile(a, c(.01,.05,.5,.95))`, if you want the first percentile, the first 5%, the mode and the 95%.

Comment: Yes but I need to calculate the percent of sales, corresponding to the certain percentile of customers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that for the upper 25%?

```
sum(df$Sale[df$Sale>=quantile(df$Sale,probs=.75)])/sum(df$Sale)
```